# При установке requirements.txt на Ubuntu выскакивает следующая ошибка?

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-2.x, amazon-web-services, virtualenv

Предыстория. Необходимо развернуть Odoo 9 на AWS. На instance установил:

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="14.04.3 LTS, Trusty Tahr"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS"
VERSION_ID="14.04".
```

Я новичок в этом деле, поэтому стал юзать вот этот алгоритм http://devdrive.ru/post/Odoo:Installation/. Остановился на установке всех необходимых пакетов командой:

> (env)$ pip install -r requirements.txt

```
warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found



file Lib/ldap.py (for module ldap) not found

file Lib/ldap/controls.py (for module ldap.controls) not found

file Lib/ldap/extop.py (for module ldap.extop) not found

file Lib/ldap/schema.py (for module ldap.schema) not found

reading manifest file 'Lib/python_ldap.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'

reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'

warning: no files found matching 'Makefile'

warning: no files found matching 'Modules/LICENSE'

writing manifest file 'Lib/python_ldap.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'

running build_ext

building '_ldap' extension

creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7

creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/Modules

x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DHAVE_SASL -DHAVE_TLS -DHAVE_LIBLDAP_R -DHAVE_LIBLDAP_R -DLDAPMODULE_VERSION=2.4.19 -IModules -I/opt/openldap-RE24/include -I/usr/include/sasl -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c Modules/LDAPObject.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/Modules/LDAPObject.o

Modules/LDAPObject.c:18:18: fatal error: sasl.h: No such file or directory

 #include <sasl.h>

                  ^

compilation terminated.

error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /home/odoo/env/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/home/odoo/env/build/python-ldap/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-oOhJcn-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/odoo/env/include/site/python2.7 failed with error code 1 in /home/odoo/env/build/python-ldap
Storing debug log for failure in /home/odoo/.pip/pip.log
```

Какой может быть выход в данном случае?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26053982/error-setup-script-exited-with-error-command-x86-64-linux-gnu-gcc-failed-wit Кажется нашёл решение

Comment: Кажется в этом месте ребята перечислили всё, что можно не поняв проблемы. У меня не пошло. В чём дело, так и не понял. Наткнулся на статью http://habrahabr.ru/post/206024/, там дядька обсуждает, почему ему не удобно пользоваться virtualenv. Он упоминает про requirements.txt. Состав этого файла может как-то стать причиной моей ошибки?

Comment: Заголовочный файл `sasl.h`, который указан в `Modules/LDAPObject.c`, на месте? По крайней мере, об этом говорит ошибка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка возникает в связи с тем, что не найден заголовочный файл(Modules/LDAPObject.c:18:18: fatal error: sasl.h: No such file or directory), необходимый для компиляции python-ldap(https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-ldap). Некоторые python пакеты содержат в себе части реализованные на С, и следовательно, их необходимо компилировать.
При этом из-за возможной несовместимости в pypi не выкладываются предскомпилировванные пакеты для linux и компиляцию нужно производить на машине.

Для установки нужных заголовочных файлов можно использовать

`sudo apt-get install libsasl2-dev`

Также возможно нужно будет установить python-dev и libldap2-dev

`sudo apt-get install python-dev libldap2-dev`

Насчет requirements.txt - этот файл просто хранит список зависимостей. Он может стать проблемой если в нем указаны некорректное имя/версия пакета или если пакет(его версия) пропал из pypi.

Comment: Либо загружать из под sudo `pip instal`

Comment: Если я правильно понял проблему, то использование `sudo pip install` не должно решить проблему, поскольку нужные заголовочные файлы все равно будут отсутствовать. Использование sudo может решить проблемы связанные с Permission denied. Например  если в процессе установки понадобится писать в директорию, на которую у текущего пользователя нет прав.